# Why do we need an eye diagram?

Tags: eye-diagram

There are some protocols with a dedicated line for clocking, and there are some protocols without a dedicated line for clocking. The last ones need a synchronization sequence which regularly zeroes the phase difference. Without the phase difference zeroing these protocols can't work due to desynchronization of the receiver and transmitter over time. Of all the bits transmitted between synchronizations, the last one will have the worst timing parameters due to jitter.

I we need to check transmission quality, it seems that the easiest and most correct way to do this is:

1. triggering on the synchronization sequence
2. accumulation the last bit edges

Why do we need an eye diagram?

Yes, we can extract the bitrate from the signal, and then we can somehow define the phase, then slice the signal and overlap sections.  It makes no sense, because protocols have the synchronization sequences.

In general, can anyone explain in what cases we can't do without an eye diagram? In what cases its use will be preferable to other types of measurements?

Answer (score 0):

You assume your triggering and your bitrate extraction and so on "can be done" in some magic way.

Truth is is that synchronization is hard, it depends on a lot of assumptions made on the transmission medium that might not be true, and something in your system has to actually do it. And an eye diagram is the right tool to check it, in many cases.

So, that's what you use an eye diagram for: checking the synchronizity. Also, checking how well the driver is able to restore "clean" signal levels. Also to see whether the equalization currently done is sufficient, or whether dispersive/multipath effects are still affecting the reception.

Comment: Today I learned that my phone replaces "bitrate" with "bizarre". I find that bitrate!

Answer (score 0):

The eye diagram is just one way of looking at how good the signal on wire and it can be used to visually read some parameters such as amplitude, overshoots, edge rise time, and how the wandering baseline of the signal affects the reception like jitter.

It enables you see the difference of receiving fast toggling sequences and slowly toggling sequences and their effect of how long it takes for the voltage levels to cross the receiver slicing threshold, i.e. how much is the received timing of single short pulse distorted during long period of constant data without toggles.

It's basically a visual diagram how the resistance and capacitance and attenuation of the cable slows and rounds the sharp transmitted signal edges into slow RC filtered shark-fin looking waveforms.

Basically it is just the waveforms of signal edges, how they look after all possible bit sequences there can be on wire, aligned to an ideal sampling clock (either recovered or using a transmit clock as reference).

It tells how good or bad the signal is at the receiver before it is out of specification and cannot be received properly any more.

So you can of course analyze all these with other methods and without an eye diagram too.

Answer (score 0):

> *Why do we need an eye diagram?*

It's a bit like asking if we can do without an oscilloscope and the answer is yes but, if you are trying to debug some hardware than, without an oscilloscope it becomes guesswork or very frustrating. An eye-diagram is a tool that specifically helps find problems and weaknesses on data transmission links and it can be very useful.

I've designed data links of several hundreds of Mbps (old hat these days) and my oscilloscope just didn't have the bandwidth to produce a decent eye diagram so, I struggled. It became a case of double-checking everything and probing around with wires until things got better. Suddenly, it starts to work and the blind probing around finally hints at what was wrong. It would have been easier to hire a high-bandwidth scope had I know it was going to take me over a week to fix it.

Answer (score -2):

> in what cases we can't do without an eye diagram

Without an eye diagram you may not be able to see some network problems such as impedance mismatches, dielectric losses etc.